# Mysql - update + insert json

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, sql-update

I got a table that has a JSON field. The default value for the field is `"NULL"` - now I'd like to update a single field of the JSON data.

```
   | ----------------- |
   | [int]  |   [JSON] |
   |  xy    |   ipdata |
   | ----------------- |
```

So the field could be something like this:

```
{ ip: "233.233.233.233", "data": "test", "name": "Peterson", "full_name": "Hanson Peterson" }
```

So I'd like to update the IP.

```
update table set ipdata = JSON_SET(ipdata, "$.ip", "newIp") where xy = 2;
```

But what happens if the field is NULL? The query above does not seems to "create" a new JSON with just the field IP. It just does nothing.

---

How can I tell mySql to insert the `{"ip": "newIp"}` if the field is empty and otherwise just update the `ip` json key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Case .. When` to handle `Null`. When the field is `null`, you can instead create [`Json_object()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) and set it:

```
UPDATE table 
SET ipdata = CASE WHEN ipdata IS NULL THEN JSON_OBJECT("ip", "newIp") 
                  ELSE JSON_SET(ipdata, "$.ip", "newIp") 
             END 
WHERE xy = "xy";
```